# How to copy subset of fields in scala without boilerplate code

Tags: scala, inheritance, copy, boilerplate

I have following classes:

```
class C {
   c1: Int,
   c2: Int,
   c3: String,
   ...
   c40: Long
}

class A extends C {
   a1: Int
}

class B extends C {
   b1: Int,
   b2: String
}
```

Then I need to create instance of B on base of instance of A and copy all values for fields inherited from C, something like:

```
new B(50, "S", c1 = a.c1, c2 = a.c2, ..., c40 = a.c40)
```

But I would like to avoid writing boilerplate like: `c1 = a.c1, c2 = a.c2, ..., c40 = a.c40`

How this could be done efficiently in scala way, but still keeping field names statically defined (not using maps or other schema-less aproach) ?

One solution could be use composition:

```
class A {
  a1: Int,
  base: C
}

class B {
  base: C,
  b1: Int,
  b2: String
}
```

And then just write: `new B(50, "S", base = a.base)`
But in that case in all other code if I need refer to value from base part I need to write `b.base.c1` instead of `b.c1` - I would like to avoid that also.

Comment: *in all other code if I need refer to value from base part I need to write b.base.c1 instead of b.c1* You can do `import b.base._` and refer to that fields effortlessly.

Comment: This approach only works if you use only one entitiy and process it in just a few places.

Comment: Do either of the answers work for you? Do you require anyone to make any clarifications?

Answer (score 0):

There is one hack that you may try to use which is using `tupled` function of case class. I can imagine you could extract fields of source class by using `unapply`, append new arguments and create the new class from the extended tuple using `tupled` function.

One of the examples that shows how to nicely combine tuples using shapeless [shapeless tupples](http://pastebin.com/bR9h1m8q)

It sounds like a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing your preposed solution ever so slightly. I am going to use a trick where `A` is not a sub-class of `C` but is an implicit sub-type.

```
class C(val c1: Int, val c2: Int)
/*
 * A does not extend C in this example.
 * Using val to provide getters
 */
class A(val a1: Int, val base: C)

/*
 * B does not extends C or A
 */
class B(val b1: Int, val base: C)

/*
 * This is where the magic happens. This implicit will
 * convert our A to a C and provide the values for C
 */
implicit def A2C(a: A): C = a.base

val myC = new C(1, 2)
// Wrap a C with our A
val myA = new A(3, myC)

// The implicit makes it seem that we are calling c1 from A
println(myA.c1)

// Now we can build a B from an A without any boilerplate
val myB = new B(4, myA)

// We need an implicit if we want to use a B as if it were a C
implicit def B2C(b: B): C = b.base

// And call C members without a messy b.base.c1 calls
println(myB.c1)

/*
 * Now assume A extended C because you need it to be a sub-type. This is
 * where a 'gotcha' raises its ugly head 
 */

// A will be considered a C in this case
def useSomeC(value: C) {
  println(value.c2)
}

// Use an A as if it were an actual sub-class of C
useSomeC(myA)

/*
 * But Generics mixes everything up for us
 */
def useGeneric[Sub <: C](value: Sub) {
  println(value.c2)
}

// Does not compile. A is not an actual sub-type of C
useGeneric(myA)

/*
 * We can get around this a couple of ways. If we are using
 * someone else's methods and they expect Sub <: C then we
 * can force the implicit conversion before we make the call
 */
val convertedToC: C = myA
useGeneric(convertedToC)

// Which can be cleaned up a bit like this
useGeneric(myA: C)

/*
 * But Scala does provide us with a tool to avoid this in our
 * own methods.
 * Note the <% instead of the <:
 */
def useSpecial[Sub <% C](value: Sub) {
  println(value.c2)
}

// Compiles and works
useSpecial(myA)
```

I hope this example helps.